# How to customize child key in Firebase?

Tags: android

I am trying to change child key in Firebase like 'Users' is a child and having different children like 'user1' , 'user2' , 'user3'.

But problem is that my code works for single application when new user installed application data is override on previous child.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using .setValue(hashMap) use .setValue(hashMap).push()

You can check if the user exists already then do not push the new one.

```
databaseReference.child("User"+Integer.toString(i)).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(!dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    databaseReference.child("User"+Integer.toString(i)).setValue(hashMap);
            }else{
               // Don't create user. Start other activity or whatever you need to do
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Let me know if this worked for you

Comment: Thanks your code work fine ! But i want new user with user id of last user+1 saved in firebase instead of don’t create new user or move to other activity. How it is possible ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand. You are asking how to get the last registered user from firebase?